# How to sort SQL table based on a column value?

Tags: sql, sorting

I have two tables

```
Name  |  Age
------------
a     |   20
b     |   15


Name  | Age(varchar)
------------------
e     |  two
d     |   one
```

then i want to show

```
Name   | Age
-----------
b      |  15
a      |  20
e      |  two
d      | one
```

How ?

Comment: I dont see what you are trying to sort, it looks more like a union?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by `union / union all` operation, 
but the data type of `Age` column of these tables seems different.

so if you try to `union all` these tables you get an error saying;

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'two' to data type int
```

So convert the data type of `age` column of `table 1` to `varchar` before `union` them

```
select id, age from (
    select id, convert(varchar(20), age) as age from tbl1
    union all
    select id, age from tbl2 
) as x
order by age
```

If you are OK with duplicate data use `union all` else `union` (`union` have additional overhead of removing duplicate data)

Note: `order by age` order age `lexicographically`

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Matt in the comments, this does like look you wish to perform a UNION query, see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180026.aspx) for an explanation on performing a UNION query.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Table2
```

**Edit:** if you wanted to order the results, you would then just add the `ORDER BY` keyword into the query.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Table2
ORDER BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Table2
ORDER BY Name, Age;
```